# Saving the date selected when UIDatePicker exiting

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I am trying to load back the date which the user last selected every time my view appears.

This IBAction is invoked when my datePicker changes value. datepick is my datePicker

I am doing this to save to it's rootVC property.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    BookingViewController *bookingVC = [[BookingViewController alloc] init];
    bookingVC.selectedDate = [datepick date];
    [bookingVC release];
}
```

Load it everytime the viewAppears.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{       
    // set datePicker Range.
    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setHour:48];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents2 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents2 setMinute:30];
    NSDate *maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:todaysDate  options:0];
    NSDate *minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents2 toDate:todaysDate  options:0];
    datepick.maximumDate = maxDate;
    datepick.minimumDate = minDate;
    if (self.dateToSet == nil) {
        [datepick setDate:minDate animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [datepick setDate:dateToSet animated:YES];
    }
    [dateComponents release];
    [dateComponents2 release];
    [gregorian release];
    choice = [datepick date];   
    choiceString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:choice];
    dateTextfield.text = choiceString;

}
```

Before pushing `dateViewController` I pass the saved date(self.selectedDate) to the `dateViewController.dateToSet` property

```
- (void)advanceBooking:(id) sender {
    DateViewController *dateViewController= [[DateViewController alloc]
                                           initWithNibName:@"DateViewController" 
                                           bundle:nil];
    if (self.selectedDate == nil) {
        selectedDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    }
    dateViewController.dateToSet = self.selectedDate;
    NSLog(@"dateVC.dateToSet :%@ selectedDate:%@", dateViewController.dateToSet, self.selectedDate); // both read as current date though it was the first call? weird.
    dateViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    dateViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dateViewController animated:YES];
    [dateViewController release];

}
```

I guess it has got something with how I init the property? When Should I init them?

Comment: @Nekto After I pop the view Controller it was on. So basically, I need it to load everytime during viewDidAppear. I think it would be better to save the selected date during viewWillDisappear.

Comment: When you pop it, it destroys, so when you add next time, it is already another instance of datePicker

Comment: @Nekto Anyway to walk about this?

Comment: Just save chosen date in controller, that pops your date picker. After alloc+init of date picker - send saved date to it from root controller.

Comment: Make sense, will try. At the same time, I had posted up what I am currently looking. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am passing back up the hierarchy, I should not create a new object of the class.

So instead, I should get back the object that was already created as such,

At DateViewController.m (child view)

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
BookingViewController *bookingVC = (BookingViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];
[bookingVC setSelectedDate:[datepick date]];
```

At BookingViewController.m (parent view)

```
if (self.selectedDate != nil) {
    dateViewController.dateToSet = self.selectedDate;
}
```

Then set it everytime during viewDidLoad at DateViewController.m

```
if (self.dateToSet == nil) {
    [datepick setDate:minDate animated:YES];
}
else {
    [datepick setDate:dateToSet animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `parentViewController` of `datePicker` when creating it:

```
dateViewController.parentViewController = self;
```

And in method `viewWillDisappear` do following:

```
((BookingViewController *)self.parentViewController).selectedDate = [datepick date];
```

In `BookingViewController` you should declare and synthesize property `NSDate *selectedData`.

But for this purposes more correct is to use protocol+delegate approach.

Comment: How should I declare the property of this parentViewController? I am getting `Request for member 'selectedDate' is something not structure or union` error on `self.parentViewController.selectedDate = [datepick date];`

Comment: Updated. Try this line `((BookingViewController *)self.parentViewController).selectedDate = [datepick date];`

Comment: Getting a crash -`[UINavigationController setSelectedDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f58f40` on viewDidDisappear and also, warning on attributes of parentViewController not matching it's superclass UIViewController. What attributes should I define for its property? I did declare property and synthesize both rootVC.`selectedDate` and dateVC.`dateToSet`

Comment: What class pushes date picker?

Comment: The RootVC is BookingViewController, subclass of UIViewController. I did add a navigation controller programatically though as I created a tab bar based projected and needed it.

Comment: Try then to decline in your DateViewController `@property (assign) UIViewController *bookController`, `@syntesize bookController` and after creating DateViewController set `dateViewController.bookController = self;`. If there will be still problems then let's chat

Comment: I have solved my question and answered it. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you load the view (`viewDidLoad`), you're re-setting the value to "now". In `viewDidLoad` you shouldn't initialize `choice`.

Comment: Wouldn't viewDidLoad be called once? I am not getting the function I wanted even when I keep navigating between views.

Comment: viewDidLoad is called every time the view is loaded. The view may unload and reload any time it is taken offscreen.